Sed command ubuntu terminal
I'm trying to figure out how to do this on Ubuntu Terminal console.
I have this file /home/users/user/config.cfg and I need every 24 hours replace 1 specific text that repeats many times on each config block.
I setup a cronjob that runs every 24 hours but I can't figure out the sed command to get this.
Example:
{"Name": "John Snow","Email": "john@snow.com","Data": [{"User-Data": "data-0001","Login-Data": "data-20240601180000","Cred-Data": "data-CR0909123"},{"User-Data": "data-0002222","Login-Data": "data-20240601180000","Cred-Data": "data-CR090911212123"},{"User-Data": "data-000112121212121","Login-Data": "data-20240601180000","Cred-Data": "data-CR090912123"}]}


I need to replace all lines were "User-Data": string appears to this:
"User-Data": "Clear",
I can't use Data* because the word Data- appears on otter json items, for example "Login-Data": "Data-20240601180000" so the mandatory key is "User-Data":  starting line.
Any idea how to do that with sed or another way.

[edit] your question to provide a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input, expected output, and your attempts to use sed for this.

You say "JSON items", but the file is .cfg. Is it JSON? If so, sed is the wrong tool, and you should use something like jq instead.

Data* isn't regex, it's glob....

@BenjaminW. actually is a json formated file saved as cfg. If jg can do the job I can try

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the terminal; you're talking about scripting. It also doesn't seem to be OS-specific. So if you remove those parts of the title, you're just left with "Sed command", which isn't descriptive at all. Please read [ask] for tips on how to write a good title and more.

Since it is JSON, you can use jq:
cfg=/home/users/user/config.cfg
jq '.Data[]."User-Data" = "Clear"' "$cfg" | sponge "$cfg"

(sponge comes from the moreutils package. Or see: jq to replace text directly on file (like sed -i))
jq will by default pretty-print its output:
{
  "Name": "John Snow",
  "Email": "john@snow.com",
  "Data": [
    {
      "User-Data": "Clear",
      "Login-Data": "data-20240601180000",
      "Cred-Data": "data-CR0909123"
    },
    {
      "User-Data": "Clear",
      "Login-Data": "data-20240601180000",
      "Cred-Data": "data-CR090911212123"
    },
    {
      "User-Data": "Clear",
      "Login-Data": "data-20240601180000",
      "Cred-Data": "data-CR090912123"
    }
  ]
}

Adding -c option will make output more compact:
{"Name":"John Snow","Email":"john@snow.com","Data":[{"User-Data":"Clear","Login-Data":"data-20240601180000","Cred-Data":"data-CR0909123"},{"User-Data":"Clear","Login-Data":"data-20240601180000","Cred-Data":"data-CR090911212123"},{"User-Data":"Clear","Login-Data":"data-20240601180000","Cred-Data":"data-CR090912123"}]}


If you must use sed, you could try with GNU sed:
sed -Ei 's/("User-Data"\s*:\s*")(\\"|[^"])*/\1Clear/g' "$cfg"

→
{"Name": "John Snow","Email": "john@snow.com","Data": [{"User-Data": "Clear","Login-Data": "data-20240601180000","Cred-Data": "data-CR0909123"},{"User-Data": "Clear","Login-Data": "data-20240601180000","Cred-Data": "data-CR090911212123"},{"User-Data": "Clear","Login-Data": "data-20240601180000","Cred-Data": "data-CR090912123"}]}

Adding -z option may help if real data is not actually a single line as shown in the example.

Working jq, thanks a lot !!
